# Can PHP write to a directory without 0777?

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, apache-http-server, php

I'm making a website builder, and I have the file `render.php`, which needs to write to users’ directories. I don't want to give each of the users’ directories 0777, but I still need to be able to write to them. Is there a way to do this?

So far I've got:

- `render` (dir) ... 0777
- `render.php` ... 777 WritesTo->
- `users` (dir) ....... 0777
- `index.php` ..... 777

I want to change this to allow render.php access to change the users’ files, but not allow the files themselves to execute code.

Comment: It's not immediately clear from your question if you need to create files, append to existing files or edit existing files. All of these operations require different permissions.

Comment: @Dennis On Ubuntu, I believe traditional permissions would be the same for append and edit (though ACLs might change things).

Comment: @Riiich: Look into ACLs. They can provide custom permissions for multiple users, not just one owner.

Comment: @cpast: Appending does not require read permissions on the file.

Comment: @Dennis Ah, that makes sense.

Comment: @Dennis I'm going to be creating editing and deleting files, hope that helps!

Comment: @cpast I'm looking to ACLs as we speak!

Answer (score 1):

If i understand you right i think this procedure should give you what you want.

1. Create a group `renderusers` for the user directory: `groupadd renderusers`
2. Change the group of the `user` directory to renderusers: `chgrp renderusers user`
3. Add the user of your apache process (apache or www-data) to this group: `usermod -G rendergroup -a apache`
4. Change the permissions of the `user` directory to include `set group ID` so that the group `renderusers` can write and change files and every newly created file will be owned by the `renderusers`group in this directory: `chmod -R 2770 user`
5. Restart apache so that it recognizes his new supplementary group

I assume that you are running php as a DSO module and not via cgi.

Comment: Hi there! Just trying this, thank you for the clear instructions. On #2 I get `chgrp: cannot access 'user': No such file or directory`. As for your question on DSO or CGI, I honestly have no idea! I installed lampp and I'm using that if it helps!

Comment: Like an idiot I thought user was the user, I mistyped the dir it's actually "users"..

I tried all of the instructions even changed the group of the render dir to renderusers but still nothing I'm afraid!

Comment: Still no access to the file :/ I've been playing around a bit but still nothing..

Comment: Could you please show the current permissions of the users directory? `ls -la users`.

Also `getent group | grep -i apache` if your apache user is apache and not www-data.

Comment: `getent group | grep -i www-data` =
`www-data:x:33:
renderusers:x:1002:richard,www-data`
`ls -la users` =
`drwxrwxr-x  5 richard    2770 4096 Mar  4 18:17 .
drwxrwxr-x 28 richard richard 4096 Mar  6 13:30 ..
drwxrwxr-x  3 richard    2770 4096 Mar  1 00:08 1
drwxrwxr-x  3 richard    2770 4096 Mar  4 18:17 3
drwxr-xr-x  3 richard    2770 4096 Feb 25 00:54 riiich`

The username I've logged onto my server is `richard`

Comment: oh sorry Riich... i had a error in step 4. Please redo step 4. I advised to execute `chgrp -R 2770 user` but it should be `chown -R 2770 user`.

Comment: Now after running `ls -l` I get:
`total 12
drwxrwxr-x 3 2770 2770 4096 Mar  1 00:08 1
drwxrwxr-x 3 2770 2770 4096 Mar  4 18:17 3` should I change all of these dirs and files to a specific group?

Comment: I'm using these permissions, because they seem to work, but how safe are they? `websiterenderer  drwxrwxrwx   3 richard  renderusers     4096 Mar  5 19:43  websiterenderer
render.php  -rwxr-xr-x  1 richard  richard   5016 Mar  5 19:43  render.php
uqpwhwyp2-q2qs5f-ri3 drwxr-xr-x  3 nobody  exobuild   4096 Mar  5 19:50  uqpwhwyp2-q2qs5f-ri3
index.php   -rw-r--r--   1 nobody   nogroup    1804 Mar  5 19:50  index.php`

Comment: The url to a users folder is: `users/(ID)/(RandomID)/index.php` so `users/1/uqpwhwyp2-q2qs5f-ri3/index.php`

Comment: Oh man, where is my head. In step 4 the error was to use either chown or chgrp. The correct command is `chmod -R 2775`.
The directories should be owned by: `www-data` with group `renderusers` and have permissions `2775` or `2770`.

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sufficiently familiar with Apache to be able to walk you through the procedure configuring the website, but I can suggest an answer at the Unix permissions level:

- Define a new group (e.g., `riiich_app`),
- do `chgrp riiich_app` and `chmod 775` on each of the users’ directories
  (and tell them not to change that), and then
- configure your web server to run your `render.php` under the `riiich_app` group.

Comment: Thank you for the clear instructions, I'm trying it as we speak!

What benefits are there in putting the directories into a group? Wouldn't the users still be able to run malicious code?

And the users can't change anything like that, at the moment it's just a simple HTML -> file builder, I'm just worried if they should happen to get in some PHP script and delete everything

Comment: If a directory (or a file, for that matter) is owned by `fred` with a group of `riiich_app`, and has a mode of 775 or 664, then Fred will have write access to it, as will anybody in the `riiich_app` group (but nobody else).  “anybody in the `riiich_app` group” should be interpreted as “any _process_ running under the `riiich_app` group ID”.    //    I believe that I don’t entirely understand your question.  What do you mean by “the users can’t change anything like that” –– are you saying that they cannot login to a shell (e.g., by `telnet` or `ssh`)?

Comment: Not at this current point in time no, I basically only have a WYSIWYG editor with add, edit and remove page functions. I just don't want them to `rmdir "../*"` (I know that's not real code, I'm just illustrating.

Answer (score -6):

You can give your webserver's username the 0777 permissions. In the case of Apache2, that is www-data.
Not exactly sure how to do that with chmod, but you can `chown www-data 777`.

Comment: I don't think giving everything 777 is exactly "safe"

Comment: Give a user[name] the 0777 permissions?  `chown www-data 777`?  That doesn’t make sense.  –1